# Logstash Grok Pattern vs Python Regex?

Tags: regex, logstash, mongrel2, logstash-grok

I am trying to configure logstash to manage my various log sources, one of which is Mongrel2. The format used by Mongrel2 is `tnetstring`, where a log message will take the form

```
86:9:localhost,12:192.168.33.1,5:57089#10:1411396297#3:GET,1:/,8:HTTP/1.1,3:200#6:145978#]
```

I want to write my own grok patterns to extract certain fields from the above format. I started by testing my regex on the above message [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/python/index.html), the regex is

```
^(?:[^:]*\:){2}([^,]*)
```

this matches `localhost`. When I use the same regex as a grok pattern in the form

```
TEST ^(?:[^:]*\:){2}([^,]*)
MONGREL %{TEST:test}
```

and configure logstash with

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => [ "message", "%{MONGREL}" ]
  }
}
```

the same regex results in the match `86:9:localhost`. I can't figure out where I am going wrong? Is is that the regex engine I was using to test is based on Python but the grok filter regex is based on Onigurama?

Currently testing it in [grokdebug](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) with the following input

```
86:9:localhost,12:192.168.33.1,5:57089#10:1411396297#3:GET,1:/,8:HTTP/1.1,3:200#6:145978#]
```

and the following pattern

```
(?<hostname>^(?:[^:]*\:){2}([^,]*))
```

resulting in

```
{
  "hostname": [
    [
      "86:9:localhost"
    ]
  ]
}
```

where I want

```
{
  "hostname": [
    [
      "localhost"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pattern like this will extract the host name:

```
^(\d+)?:(\d+)?:(?<hostname>[^,]+),
```

Or writing it in a similar manner that you already wrote it:

```
^(?:[^:]*\:){2}(?<hostname>[^,]*)
```

The capture name needs to be inside the parenthesis that you want to capture... your pattern was capturing everything up to that point.

Answer (score 1):

Give http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ a try. This is the best way to debug grok patterns that don't result in hair loss.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that I was trying grokdebug. I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that I am both losing my hair *and* writing logstash grok patterns.