# Chaining grok filter patterns for logstash

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to configure logstash to manage my various log sources, one of which is Mongrel2. The format used by Mongrel2 is `tnetstring`, where a log message will take the form

```
86:9:localhost,12:192.168.33.1,5:57089#10:1411396297#3:GET,1:/,8:HTTP/1.1,3:200#6:145978#]
```

I want to write my own grok patterns to extract certain fields from the above format. I received help on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26013516/logstash-grok-pattern-vs-python-regex/26018844#26018844) trying to extract the host. So if in `grok-patterns` I define

```
M2HOST ^(?:[^:]*\:){2}(?<hostname>[^,]*)
```

and then in the logstash conf specify

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => [ "message", "%{M2HOST}" ]
  }
}
```

it works as expected. The problem I now have  is I want to specify multiple patterns e.g. M2HOST, M2ADDR etc. I tried defining additional ones in the same grok-patterns file

```
M2HOST ^(?:[^:]*\:){2}(?<hostname>[^,]*)
M2ADDR ^(?:[^:]*\:){3}(?<address>[^,]*)
```

and changing the logstash conf

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => [ "message", "%{M2HOST} %{M2ADDR}" ]
  }
}
```

but now I just get the error `_grokparsefailure`.

Comment: your problem here is the concatenation, think replacing the M2HOST and M2ADDR by their regex, you'll get `^(?:[^:]*\:){2}(?<hostname>[^,]*) ^(?:[^:]*\:){3}(?<address>[^,]*)` You have a start of line in the middle of your match which obviously can't work. The main idea with pultiples ALIASES is to split the regex part to reuse them but not to magically merge them.

Comment: ah ok. What I want is to apply the M2HOST regex to the message, and then the M2ADDR to the message. Do you know what the correct syntax would be?

Comment: Well I would work with the grok tester you already know, trynig to match each field, once that done you may split the interesting parts. for this exmeple I would say (tested) `(?:[^:]*:){2}(?<hostname>[^,]*)[^:]*:(?<address>[^,]*)` would do

Comment: Excellent, thank you. That worked (missing a closing bracket)

Comment: In fact there were an extraneous one before (?<address which was an error from copy pasting your parts :) full answer below done with grokdebug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with your sample input from other question and with some guessing about the values names the full match would be:

`(?:[^:]*:){2}(?<hostname>[^,]*)[^:]*:(?<address>[^,]*)[^:]*:(?<pid>[^#]*)[^:]*:(?<time>[^#]*)[^:]*:(?<method>[^,]*)[^:]*:(?<query>[^,]*)[^:]*:(?<protocol>[^,]*)[^:]*:(?<code>[^#]*)[^:]*:(?<bytes>[^#]*).*`

Producing:

```
{
  "hostname": [
    [
      "localhost"
    ]
  ],
  "address": [
    [
      "192.168.33.1"
    ]
  ],
  "pid": [
    [
      "57089"
    ]
  ],
  "time": [
    [
      "1411396297"
    ]
  ],
  "method": [
    [
      "GET"
    ]
  ],
  "query": [
    [
      "/"
    ]
  ],
  "protocol": [
    [
      "HTTP/1.1"
    ]
  ],
  "code": [
    [
      "200"
    ]
  ],
  "bytes": [
    [
      "145978"
    ]
  ]
}
```